# CSS using styled-components and color themes messing up

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, input, styled-components

[Image of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6soMR.png)
So i have themes and colors defined in my React app.
Everything works well except these labels. When i change the theme to green and then change it back to blue and then when i focus on the input, the color again changes to the opposite theme. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Also this problem only occurs after i change the theme. Initially when i focus on the input the label remains blue.

This is my code for the theme part.

```
    {
        type: "light",
        primaryColor1: "#33b2ff", //lightest
        primaryColor2: themeColor === "blue" ? "#009fff" : "#00b05d", //ChangeColor()
        primaryColor3: "#007fcc", //darkest
        textColor1: "#111", //darkest
        textColor2: "#555",
        textColor3: "#888", //lightest
        backgroundColor1: "#fcfcfc", //lightest
        backgroundColor2: "#e3e3e3",
        backgroundColor3: "#cacaca", //darkest
        borderColor: "009fff",
        white: "#fff",
        black: "000",
    }
```

This object returns all my theming colors but the primary color part is where it checks a state called themeColor which when set to blue, returns blue as the primary color for the entire app or green if otherwise. The entire app is wrapped with useContext's Provider and the Theme is passed via styled-components' ThemeProvider like so:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

<ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme,themeToggler,themeColor,setThemeColor}}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={themeStyle}>
                {children}
            </ThemeProvider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
```

This is the CSS part using styled-components for the Input and Label elements:

```
export const Input = styled.input( ({theme}) => `
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background: ${theme.backgroundColor3};
    border: 0;
    color: ${theme.textColor1};
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Montserrat;

    &:focus
    {
        outline: none;
    }

    &[type=password]
    {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
`);

export const Label = styled.label( ({theme}) => `
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    color: ${theme.textColor3};
    cursor: text;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 5.5%;
    border: 1px solid ${theme.borderColor};
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    background: none;

    ${Input}:focus + &,
    ${Input}:not(:placeholder-shown) + &
    {
        background: ${theme.primaryColor2};
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem 0.2rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        top: -15%;
        left: 3%;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        color: #fff;
    }

`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe !important rule solve your problem. You can try write !important after your css properties.
Example:
`background: ${theme.primaryColor2} !important;`

Comment: hello, thank you for answering. I tried it but it's still no good. I'm starting to think this is a problem being cause by react states and calls to the states or something. Still not able to figure it out.